# JMeter test is not stopping while running in non-gui mode even after defining the loop count as 1

Tags: testing, jmeter

I prepared a simple JMeter script for login and logout. Executed the test with 20 users, 10 sec ramp-up and 1 loop count from UI. The test was successfully completed.

When I triggered the same test in non-gui mode with same number of users, ramp-up and loop count, the test didn't stopped at all. It repeated the users for multiple times, not sure why and how.

I am using JMeter 5.6 version for testing. Can anyone help me in identifying the issue?

I have allocated a heap size of 1GB in JMeter.bat

I ran the below command to execute the script in non-gui mode:
jmeter -n -t C:\Users\bsahu\Desktop\Scripts<Script_name>.jmx -l C:\Users\bsahu\Desktop\Results\10JULY<Result_file_name>.jtl

I am observing that the test is running continuously, but it should stop after 20 users complete their execution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're facing [JMeter issue 6008](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/6008), the options are in:

1. Insert  `<boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>` line into the [.jmx script directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
2. Downgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
3. Upgrade to [JMeter 5.6.1](https://lists.apache.org/thread/59w4nhhltyp5h4clxphxxoz6xql4cyz4) which contains the fix
4. Switch to another Thread Group like [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)